# Logging into Binance.com via VPN gives: "Network unavailable,please refresh and try again"

Tags: binance

When using my VPN I get the following error: Network unavailable,please refresh and try again

However it works fine when using it without VPN. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bypass that check goto: hw_login.html instead of login.html when you are on the binance login page. **Just replace login.html with hw_login.html**